# Split Clob containing XML

Tags: sql, regex, xml, oracle, plsql

I have a table containing, in a clob column, a value like this: `<root><node><a>text1a</a><b>text1b</b></node><node><a>text2a</a><b>text2b</b></node></root>`

Using PL/SQL I need to query it and obtain this output in two rows:

```
<node><a>text1a</a><b>text1b</b></node>
<node><a>text2a</a><b>text2b</b></node>
```

It could be more the 4000 chars each one. 
Tag  must be included in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert clob to xmltype and use xmltable to parse it:

```
with s as (select '<root><node><a>text1a</a><b>text1b</b></node><node><a>text2a</a><b>text2b</b></node></root>' c from dual)
select x.node node_xml, x.node.getclobval() node_clob
from s,
xmltable(
'/root/node'
passing xmltype(s.c)
columns
node xmltype path '.'
) x;

NODE_XML                                   NODE_CLOB                                 
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
<node><a>text1a</a><b>text1b</b></node>    <node><a>text1a</a><b>text1b</b></node>   
<node><a>text2a</a><b>text2b</b></node>    <node><a>text2a</a><b>text2b</b></node>
```

Answer (score -1):

Original data is not in varchar; it is in some LOB.  If you are ok with returning 2 lobs, look up PLSQL table functions (to put a function in from clause) and utilizing dbms_lob package return 2 rows where each row is a LOB as well.

If you want to return it as varchar data, then you have the 4000 limit.  All you can do is return in multiple rows of 4000 and combine them all in your client software.

You can see this link where there is a solution to split blob into 4000 byte strings.  https://medium.com/@thesaadahmad/a-blobs-journey-from-the-database-to-the-browser-98884261e137

Comment: dbms_lob package - I thought I referenced that and also that plsql function in from clause.  I am not going to cut/paste code again here.

I sometimes wonder if people get paid by "downvotes"!  Anyways interesting to see that folks don't read answers or questions but insist on providing their input.  Must be some secret stackoverflow meeting somewhere....

Comment: I need to return a clob.  

I read the amount parameter in DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR cannot be more than 32767.While each node I have cold be longer.

I think maybe a RegExpr could solve but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: You really have only two options a) use dbms_lob substr and convert it back to lob and return to your client.  Your client needs to be able to process it.  But if you client can process it, why do dbms_lob at all; simply return big string and parse on client b) Return multiple rows from DB of 4000 each with a seqnum.  Now your client simply sees varchar but needs to know that it needs to read multiple rows and concatenate on its side.  The link provides latter option.